# How do you print to PDF without distortion of image on Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I'm using Windows 10.  When I take a screenshot, it looks perfectly crisp in Paint.  However, if I print it using Microsoft Print to PDF as my printer, the resulting PDF is fuzzy.  How do I fix this distortion so that the PDF looks crisp?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use something else for printing to PDF. There are plenty of free options available. I personally use the print-to-pdf feature that comes packaged with Foxit Reader (an Adobe Reader alternative).

It sounds like the Microsoft Print to PDF is compressing the images too much when it writes them to PDF.

Comment: I installed Foxit, but when I open the png file, it immediately becomes distorted.

Comment: To clarify... you installed foxit, went back and reprinted the png using _foxit's_ pdf printer, then it still opened the newly created pdf distorted? Is that correct?